# Server sends Welcome message more than once using select()

Tags: select, server, client

I'm currently having an issue with pop3 server which is based on select() function. Basically server holds multiple clients at once, but Welcome message sends as many times as is the number of connected client.
[This is an example of messages sent to clients.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JyAr.png)

```
//file descriptor, array of clients 
fd_set readset;
int sock_arr[30];
int max_fd, rc;

servsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
/*...*/
max_fd = servsock;

do
{
FD_ZERO(&readset);
FD_SET(servsock, &readset);

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    rc = sock_arr[i];
    if (rc > 0)
        FD_SET(rc, &readset);
    if (rc > max_fd)
        max_fd = rc;
}
activity = select(max_fd + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

if (activity < 0)
{
 perror("  select() failed");
 break;
}

if (activity == 0)
{
 printf("  select() timed out.  End program.\n");
 break;
}
```

Message is sent as many times as is the number of connected client e.g.
if first client is connected the message is sent once
if second client is connected the message is sent twice etc.

```
 //here server accepts new connections
if (FD_ISSET(servsock, &readset)) {
    serv_socket_len = sizeof(addr);
    peersoc = accept(servsock,(struct sockaddr *) &addr, &serv_socket_len);
    if (peersoc < 0) {
        error("Accept failed!\n", ERR_SCK);
    }
    else {
        char message[256];
        strcat(message, reply_code[1]);
        strcat(message, reply_code[3]);
        strcat(message, reply_code[0]);
        //Welcome message
        send(peersoc, message, strlen(message), 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            if (sock_arr[i] == 0) {
                sock_arr[i] = peersoc;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
//server processing input messages from clients using threads
/*...*/
```

I have no idea what causes I assume something with file descriptors. Please give me some advice if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved I have forgotten to clear buffer for sending message

```
...
char message[256];
memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
...
```